# Interface Builder Constraints Problems

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm following an ios development tutorial and having trouble with auto layout and constraints in xcode's interface builder. I have xcode 10.3.

I've put 2 pairs of objects on the storyboard, each pair with a label (text = "???") and a button.

I run in the simulator without autolayout using iphone 8, and it looks fine:

[image]

Then I am instructed to use auto-layout, so I select the top label and then add new alignment constraints, choosing "horizontally in center" and pressing "Add 1 constraint":

[image]

Once I run this in the simulator the label that I've horizontally centered renders at the very top of the viewable area. I have followed this tutorial exactly and tried multiple times but each time with this problem.

[image]

The tutorial seems to have been written for an earlier version of xcode in mind.

Comment: If you add one constraint, you have to add the others. So far, all you've added is one "centerX" constraint on the label.

Comment: You need at least one more constraint - you have said that you want the label in he horizontal centre but you haven't constrained the vertical position

Comment: As a side note, if the tutorial is telling you to add ***only*** that horizontal constraint, it's a bad tutorial. Find another one.

Comment: The tutorial is the book <i>ios programming</i> edition 6 from big nerd ranch. The screenshot in the book specifies that after selecting the top label and adding the first constraint ("Add new alignment constraints and choosing "horizontally in center") to then select the rest of the UI objects and click the "Add new constraints" dialog, choosing "Align" checkbox and selecting "horizontal centers".

The problem might be, at least in my version of xcode, there doesn't seem to be an "Align" checkbox in the "Add new constraints" dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define more constraints, as in:

[image: Constraints]

> Result

[image: result]

Or even better, use vertical [Stack Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html); so you would need to define only two constraints (center horizontally / center vertically):

[image: stack view]

You should definitely follow another tutorial.

Comment: Yes I contacted a fellow employee who is very experienced at ios development and he helped me. The book is just not correct, at least for my version of xcode.